# WebRtc connection in dart:html, incomplete API?

Tags: dart, webrtc, dart-html

What would be the equivalent in dart of the following javascript snippet?

```
myPeerConnection.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
  return myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
})
```

The straight translation:

```
final offer = await myPeerConnection.createOffer();
myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
```

does not compile because `createOffer()` eventually returns a `RtcSessionDescription` and setLocalDescription accepts only a `Map`.

And `RtcSessionDescription` does not have a nice way to convert to a `Map` in the API.

Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few things, this works in my use case (at least in Chrome):

```
final offer = await myPeerConnection.createOffer();
myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription({"sdp": offer.sdp, "type": offer.type ?? 'offer'});
```